# "Don't I just bet you were"

Tags: idiomatic-language, subject-auxiliary-inversion

What does ""Don't I just bet you were" mean in the following?

> A: I was about to demonstrate how to use the tool.
>
> B: Don't I just bet you were.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess it probably means *I did believe you were about to demonstrate ...*. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Did you actually hear this? What dan says makes some sense (i.e. it sounds like an affirmation of what A said), but the whole remark has a hostile/accusatory tone that makes me wonder what else was going on in that situation. Perhaps it was meant to be sarcastic?

Comment: It can only be sarcasm. It would usually not be anything other than: Oh yeah, I bet you were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect this phrase and similar phrases to be uses most often in a sarcastic manner.

> A: I was about to demonstrate how to use the tool.
>
> B: Don't I just bet you were.

With the p[roper tone, B might well mean "I don't for a moment believe you were going to do anything of the sort." In my experience "I just bet" and similar phrases are most often used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

As @dan commented, it means *B did believe A was about to demonstrate how to use the tool*.

**Just** is an adverb expressing agreement, so the phrase "Don't I just!" is an interjection meaning, essentially, "yes".

**I bet** is said to show that you understand why someone has a particular opinion or feels a particular way.

This is a mix of the two expressions.